# Python setuptools: package directory does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging

I have a project with this `setup.py` file:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="",
    author_email="",
    description="",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="./src", exclude=("./tests",)),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.8',
)
```

This is my project directory structure (first two levels):

```
$ tree -L 2
.
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── src
│   └── my_pkg
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── data
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── integration
    ├── __pycache__
    └── unit
```

When I run any setuptools command, I get the following error:

```
$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'my_pkg' does not exist
```

The same happens for other commands like `python setup.py develop` and `python setup.py bdist-wheel`.

I suspect that it has to do with the `src` directory, as specified in the `find_packages(where="./src")` call in the `setup.py`. However, I've been following the [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html), and it does look the the `my_pkg` module is discovered at some point.

Why does `build_py` fail to find it?

Comment: Change to ```packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="src", exclude=("tests",))```

Comment: @SreeramTP That makes no difference.

Comment: ```setuptools.setup(
    name="",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="",
    author_email="",
    description="",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    package_dir={"": str("src")},
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.8',
)``` Can you try this? @Carsten

Comment: Adding the `package_dir` seems to do the trick indeed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`find_packages()` automatically generates package names. That is, in your case all it does is generate `['my_pkg']`. It doesn't actually tell `setup()` where to find `my_pkg`, just that it should expect to find a package called `my_pkg` somewhere. You have to separately tell `setup()` where it should look for packages. Is this confusing and counter intuitive? Yes. Anyway, you can tell `setup()` where to find `my_pkg` by using the `package_dir` argument. eg.

```
package_dir={"":"src"}
```

Comment: hi, is there a way to do this with `setup.cfg`?

Comment: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#using-a-src-layout

Comment: Actually, I do not find the documentation very clear for projects with flat structures. It worked for me by (instead of listing all submodules) only doing in ```setup.cfg```:
```[options]package_dir = 
mypkg = name_of_your_package```