# Setuptools creates multiple packages instead of one overarching package

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, packaging

I am trying to create a minimalistic example to understand how setuptools works.

I have the following folder structure:

```
my_package/
  src/
    pkg1/
      __init__.py
    pkg2/
      __init__.py
    excluded_pkg/
      __init__.py
    __init__.py
setup.py
```

My setup.py includes this:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup


setup(
    name='inversiontestproblems',
    version='0.0.1',
    install_requires=[
        'requests',
        'importlib-metadata; python_version == "3.8"',
    ],
    packages=find_packages(
        where='src',
        include=['pkg*'],
        exclude=['excluded_pkg'],
    ),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
)
```

If I create wheel with this setup and install it with pip install, it makes pkg1 and pkg2 directly accessible and drops the package name. What this means is I could open a python terminal and type `import pkg1`, but I can not write `import my_package`.

To fix it I tried to change setup.py to this:

```
...
package_dir={"my_package": "src"},
...
```

But now I get this error: `error: package directory 'pkg1' does not exist`. This error was also discussed here, here they suggested to change `"my_package"` to `""` to make it work:
[Python setuptools: package directory does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64207149/python-setuptools-package-directory-does-not-exist)

I am at my wits end. The Setuptools website does not help either. I would appreciate some help. How to I create a single package containing sub-packages with setuptools?

Comment: I want to understand the last line correctly before writing an answer or to know if I know the answer or not. So you want to do something like `from my_package import pkg1`, right? Or should you be able to `import my_package`, `import pkg1`?

Comment: Thanks for the question, you are correct. I want to be able to do `from my_package import pkg1`. But it seems that I can only have one: Either I can use commands like `where=' '` and `exclude=[]`, or I can specify the package name in the line `package_dir={"my_package": "src"}`. But I can't find a way to do both.

Answer (score 1):

please try to rearrange your directory structure like below

```
my_package
   ├── my_package
   │   ├── excluded_pkg
   │   │   └── __init__.py
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   ├── pkg1
   │   │   └── __init__.py
   │   └── pkg2
   │       └── __init__.py
   └── setup.py
```

In setup.py, the code will be

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup


setup(
    name='inversiontestproblems',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(
        exclude=['my_package.excluded_pkg'],
    ),

)
```

Hope this solve your problem.